# Redshift SQL: Check if same set of values are IN and NOT IN two different columns of table

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I am running a lookup on a large Redshift table (petabytes) where a set of 5,000 names are in a column named BUYERS and not in a column named SELLERS. The goal is to exclude rows where the buy is an internal transfer (aka buyer is not the seller).

I'm curious if there is a more efficient way than simply the following

```
buyers in ('EXAMPLE 1','EXAMPLE 2') and sellers not in ('EXAMPLE 1','EXAMPLE 2')
```

Comment: That seems like the most reasonable logic to me.

Comment: Petabyte\*s\*, plural?  ae you sure?  a max sized DS2 cluster can do about a petabyte, and you'd need something like, what, 40 ra3 16x nodes for two petabytes.  Do you really have a cluster this size?

Comment: The question can only be answered if the sort type and sorting order of the table is known.

Comment: Sorry, @MaxGanzII, the cluster is 1.5 petabytes, I dont have SVV_TABLE_INFO permission to check the table size but its huge as well.

Comment: I believe you about the cluster size, although the question of the table size is still open, but this seems peculiar.  Someone is paying a *LOT* of money for a cluster that size, but - no offense here! - they've got staff who need to ask on SO about how to optimize queries?

Comment: BTW, what node types are you using in the cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"WHERE NOT IN" can create inefficient executions but this is so simple that I hope the Redshift query compiler should optimize this code.  If the "IN" list gets long this can get very slow.  Generally "WHERE NOT EXIST" is more efficient than "WHERE NOT IN" but again in this simple case it should be noticeable.

For something this simple (2 values) you can try -

```
buyers in ('EXAMPLE 1','EXAMPLE 2') and sellers <> 'EXAMPLE 1' and sellers <> 'EXAMPLE 2'
```

and see if there is any speed up.  I hope this make no difference.

Comment: Gotcha, actually the list is several thousand values

Comment: So yes, in that case NOT EXIST will likely be (somewhat) faster than NOT IN.  If the list is really long and is in a table you can LEFT JOIN that table and check for NULL - for really long list this can be faster still (especially if you make the "not in" list a DIST ALL table).  Bottom line - large "not in" lists combined with clustered databases means it may take some experimenting to find an ideal process.